# Prevent AucTeX from changing font within some tags

Tags: latex, auctex, buffers

When I'm using AucTex, I tend to have problems with how the package formats the fonts I use within tags such as `\textit{}`. It appears that AucTeX wants to display an italicized version of the buffer's font, but if it does not exist, I get some garbage characters.
[[image: Emacs AucTeX font bug]
Is there some way I can prevent AucTeX from requesting a non-existent italic version of the font I'm using when I use these commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your cursor on the text in question and do `C-u C-x =`. Near the bottom of buffer `*Help*` you will see the name of the face used for that text. Use `M-x customize-face FACE`, where `FACE` is that face name.